# find and replace string in text file (powershell script) with cell value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create button in Excel which will call VBA script which will change text file.

I have text file which looks like:

```
String 1 
String2 
... 
String 123 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.example.com/publicdocs/files/iceu/2022/07/IPE0729F.CSV.zip
-OutFile C:\folder\files\IPE0802F.CSV.zip

String 125 
.... 
String 999
```

What I need is to change string:

> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri
> https://www.example.com/publicdocs/files/iceu/2022/07/ABB0729F.CSV.zip
> -OutFile C:\folder\files\ABB0802F.CSV.zip

and replace dates with values from cells, i.e.:
replace **2022** with

```
Range("A1").Value
```

Replace **07**
with

```
Range("A2").Value
```

Replace **0729**
with `Range("A3").Value`

Replace **0802**
With `Range("A4").Value`

So I need to find this string in text file, modify it and save file.
Maybe someone can help with that since looks like I have no enough knowledge to achieve it (

Ok, here I can find needed string, but I dont know how to replace whole string with updated one:

```
Sub updatePS()

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim FSO, FileIn, FileOut, strTmp

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileIn = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\powershell.ps1", ForReading)
Set FileOut = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\powershell2.ps1", ForWriting, True)

Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, strTmp, "Invoke-WebRequest", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
              ' Here I should add code to replace updated string
        End If
    End If
Loop

FileIn.Close
FileOut.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Will **all the time** strings to be replaced be the same? I mean, if you make the change and save the file, it will remain with the new data. Shouldn't it be better to use it as a kind of template and save the modified content in another folder (with the same name)?

Comment: Yes, strings to be replaced will be same. THere couple of strings in the scripts where date has to be updated daily. If I got you correct you mean that every time updated file will be saved in some folder with new name? I am ok to save in new folder, but name should be the same to be able to schedule script to run automatically.

Comment: I think it is quite easy to make kind of template, let say write script in cells and update cell values and then save result in text file, but i find it not very nice solution, but probably will use it if will not get help here

Comment: I said "with the same name"... Now, will all the time "ABB" be before "0729" and " F.CSV.zip" after? The same for "IPE" in front of 0802 and "F.CSV.zip" after?

Comment: I was trying to say something different, respectively: The actual script to be consider a kind of template and create a piece of code to process it as you need. Otherwise, the code will work only once! If the file will be saved, next time "\07\", "0729" and "0802" **will not exist, anymore** to be used as references when run the code next time... I do not know how you handle the actual script, of course. But I will try helping with a piece of code only if I can imagine a scenario to make something **useful**, not just didactic, for one use...

Comment: On the other hand you can proceed in a different way, too. I mean to save the script, but keeping the strings to be replaced in an array and **drop the array content in the worksheet, on column A:A, after processing**. In this way, the new data will be used next time as strings to be replaced...

Comment: Can you answer the clarification questions regarding the strings before and after something to be replaced, please? At least, would the string after will **always be "F.C**?

Comment: I am asking for that kind of clarifications because they are necessary! For instance, if you try replacing "07", with "08" without using "/07/", "0729" will be transformed in "**08**29"...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer, I was out.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right when you saying that  "\07\", "0729" and "0802" will not exist, anymore. They will be replaced with actual data, which will be replaced with new actual data next day etc etc. Every business day script gonna run and change powershell script. 
So basically my idea was:
Since string lways the same except dates, I was thinking to find the string which starts with Invoke-WebRequest and replace whole string with the new string which will be concatenated from different pieces, including necessary dates which I can get from some cells for e.g.

Comment: So that was my idea, but I don't have enough knowledge in VBA yet.... Quite easy in Linux, but here its nightmare for me ))))

Comment: But, my questions ar already too old... Why don't you try the code I posted and do not think to the variant  I  proposed at the end of the answer?

Comment: The whole string is the same except dates, so ABB always there and F.CSV.zip as well

Comment: Hah, i didnt read you code yet, started to answer your comments )
Will give it a try!

Comment: Do you know how to see the result of `Debug.Print`? If not open `Immediate Window` pressing `Ctrl + G` being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not answer all my clarification questions...

The the next solution assumes that "2022" and "07" are both between "/" two such characters and  "0729" / "0802" have a following suffix of "F.C" string. Otherwise, the code could strictly replace the strings you asked for, but the possibility to **also replace in different locations** exists:

```
Sub ModifScript()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, fso As Object, ts As Object, sPath As String, sFile As String, strText As String
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'use here your real path, please!
    sFile = "powershell.ps1"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.getFile(sPath & sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        strText = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    
    Dim chngTxt As String, chngText As String, frstChar As Long, frstChar2 As Long, endChar As Long
    frstChar = 1 'first character, where from InStr start evaluation
     frstChar = InStr(frstChar, strText, "Invoke-WebRequest") 'the digit number where the necessary string (to be changed) starts
      frstChar2 = InStr(frstChar + Len("Invoke-WebRequest"), strText, "OutFile C:\") 'this returns the real ending of the necessary string...
      
     endChar = InStr(frstChar2 + Len("Invoke-WebRequest"), strText, "F.CSV.zip") 'the digit number where the necessary string ends

     'string to be processed:
     chngTxt = Mid(strText, frstChar, endChar + Len("F.CSV.zip") - frstChar)
       Debug.Print chngTxt   'just to visually check that the correct string to be changed has been returned
       
       chngText = Replace(Replace(chngTxt, "/2022/", "/" & sh.Range("A1").value & "/"), "/07/", "/" & sh.Range("A2").value & "/")
       chngText = Replace(Replace(chngText, "0729F.C", sh.Range("A3").value & "F.C"), "0802F.C", sh.Range("A4").value & "F.C")
       Debug.Print chngText 'just to visually check that the string to be changed has been correctly changed
       
     'replace the changed string in the original file text:
     strText = Replace(strText, chngTxt, chngText) 'the changed whole string!
      Debug.Print strText
      Dim scriptFold As String, pathToFile As String
        If Dir(sPath & "Scripts", vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sPath & "Scripts" 'create "Scripts" folder if it does not exist
        
        pathToFile = sPath & "Scripts\" & sFile
       Open pathToFile For Output As #1
            Print #1, strText
       Close #1
End Sub
```

The above code saves the processed file content in a new folder ("Scripts), created by the code, if not exists...

Basically, you should use the same script file, but **always update the column B:B of the active sheet with the changed string (taken from A:A)**. It is necessary to only replace in code `"/2022/"` with `"/" & Sh.Range("B1").value & "/"`, `"/07/"` with `"/" & Sh.Range("B2").value & "/"`, `"0729F.C"` with `Sh.Range("B2").value & "S.C"` and so on...

**Edited**:

Please, test the next variant. It does not need the existing strings to be replaced, anymore. This code is able to firstly identify/extract the strings to be replaced and then replaces them with the one from the Excel sheet:

```
Sub ModifScript_Next()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, fso As Object, ts As Object, sPath As String, sFile As String, strText As String
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sFile = "powershell.ps1"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.getFile(sPath & sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        strText = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    
    Dim chngTxt As String, chngText As String, frstChar As Long, frstChar2, endChar As Long
    frstChar = 1 'first character, where from InStr start evaluation
     frstChar = InStr(frstChar, strText, "Invoke-WebRequest") 'the digit number where the necessary string (to be changed) starts
      frstChar2 = InStr(frstChar + Len("Invoke-WebRequest"), strText, "OutFile C:\") 'this returns the real ending of the necessary string...
      
     endChar = InStr(frstChar2 + Len("Invoke-WebRequest"), strText, "F.CSV.zip") 'the digit number where the necessary string ends
     'string to be processed:
     chngTxt = Mid(strText, frstChar, endChar + Len("F.CSV.zip") - frstChar)
       Debug.Print chngTxt   'just to visually check that the correct string to be changed has been returned
       Dim frstStr As String, secStr As String, thrdStr As String, fourStr As String, frstC As Long, secCh As Long
        'extract first string:
         frstC = InStr(1, chngTxt, "docs/files/iceu/")
          secCh = InStr(frstC + Len("docs/files/iceu/"), chngTxt, "/")
           frstStr = Mid(chngTxt, frstC + Len("docs/files/iceu/"), secCh - (frstC + Len("docs/files/iceu/")))
           'Debug.Print "_" & frstStr & "_"  'OK
           
        'extract second string:
        frstC = secCh + 1
         secCh = InStr(frstC, chngTxt, "/IPE")
           secStr = Mid(chngTxt, frstC, secCh - frstC)
           'Debug.Print "_" & secStr & "_"  'OK
           
        'extract third string:
        frstC = secCh + Len("/IPE")
         secCh = InStr(frstC, chngTxt, "F.CSV")
          thrdStr = Mid(chngTxt, frstC, secCh - frstC)
          'Debug.Print "_" & thrdStr & "_": 'Stop 'OK
          
        'extract fourth string:
        frstC = InStr(secCh + Len("F.CSV"), chngTxt, "files\IPE")
         secCh = InStr(frstC + Len("files\IPE"), chngTxt, "F.CSV")
          fourStr = Mid(chngTxt, frstC + Len("files\IPE"), secCh - (frstC + Len("files\IPE")))
          'Debug.Print "_" & fourStr & "_": Stop 'OK
    
       chngText = Replace(Replace(chngTxt, "/" & frstStr & "/", "/" & sh.Range("A1").value & "/"), "/" & secStr & "/", "/" & sh.Range("A2").value & "/")
       chngText = Replace(Replace(chngText, thrdStr & "F.C", sh.Range("A3").value & "F.C"), fourStr & "F.C", sh.Range("A4").value & "F.C")
       Debug.Print chngText 'just to visually check that the string to be changed has been correctly changed
       
     'replace the changed string in the original file text:
     strText = Replace(strText, chngTxt, chngText) 'the changed whole string!
      'Debug.Print strText
      Dim scriptFold As String, pathToFile As String
        If Dir(sPath & "Scripts", vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sPath & "Scripts" 'create "Scripts" folder if it does not exist
        
        pathToFile = sPath & "Scripts\" & sFile
       Open pathToFile For Output As #1
            Print #1, strText
       Close #1
End Sub
```

After testing it and concluding that it fits what you want, you can overwrite the existing file in the last lines. I mean, `pathToFile` must be `sPath & sFile`. And, of course, in such a case the sequence using a different folder should be eliminated.

Comment: @Роман Рослый But you should use "C:\"  for `sPath`. The necessary full name is obtained by concatenation of `sPath` with `sFile`... This split is necessary to create (in `sPath`) a new folder ("Scripts"), where to create the new `.ps1` file. At least, to let you check if it is correctly processed... I am asking myself if your user has enough permissions to write on C... That's why I've chosen the path of the workbook where the code runs...

Comment: Yes it works! So the idea is to keep first file as a template and script will always work with this file and will create new file with correct string? Did I get it right?

Comment: @Роман Рослый If nobody needs to modify the template and you only need to replace the strings you asked for, you must only place the respective values in the appropriate cells. Then, processing of the `.ps1` file will be done from its new path.

Comment: @Роман Рослый The other option was to save the script in the place where it is and update the Excel active sheet with the copied values. I mean, the code will firstly copy "A1:A4" in "B1:B4" then it should be adapted as I clearly (I think) suggested at the end of the answer. I mean: " It is necessary to only replace in code `"/2022/"` with `"/" & Sh.Range("B1").value & "/"`, `"/07/"` with `"/" & Sh.Range("B2").value & "/", "0729F.C"` with `Sh.Range("B2").value & "S.C"` and so on"... Then you only need to update A:A cells with the values to be changed. Choose what looks more convenient!

Comment: @Роман Рослый It is late in my country and I will close my laptop after some minutes. If need something else, I will be available tomorrow.

Comment: @Роман Рослый It is a mistake in my code... I did not observe that there are two cases of  strings ending with "F.CSV.zip" in the text slice I firstly extract to process it... That's why replacing of "0802" cannot take place, because the string to be processed does not include it. I had in mind a different approach. No much available time right now, but I think, after receiving your answers to my clarification questions, I can replace the strings in discussion **without even knowing them**. I mean, it looks that they can  be previously extracted...

Comment: @Роман Рослый For now, corrected the above existing version...

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, I tested updated script, its logic better, but it makes wrong replacement (I put 11111 in A1, 22222 in A2 etc.):
`Invoke-WebRequest https:/22222/IPE33333F.CSV.zip -OutFile C:\path\path\IPE0802F.CSV.zip`
from
`Invoke-WebRequest https://www.example.com/publicdocs/path2/path2/2022/08/IPE0803F.CSV.zip -OutFile C:\path\path\IPE0802F.CSV.zip`

Comment: @Роман Рослый Of course it fails if you play with strings... How the code to recognize "/path2/path2"? It recognize **only what you show in your question**! It is not a human being to 'understand' what abstract folders name you used... If you look to the code, it searches for "docs/files/iceu/" and **determines position to extract based on this specific string**...  I am afraid you are far away from the strings manipulations field, no offence. If those subfolders name can be modified **you should mention that**? The code can even count backslashes, but I could come only with what I could see.

Comment: Confirm - all works just fine! 
I mentioned "path" just to make it easier to copy/paste here, real string was provided earlier.
I made small change and can see that everything works correctly.
Thanks you very much @FaneDuru!!!

Comment: @Роман Рослый If so, it should be impossible to return as you wrote in your comment, I think... Of course, if you used the code exactly as it is, on strings as the ones you show in your question, adapting only the path... Can you show what changes were necessary? To understand them and eventually adapt the answer for somebody else who may be interested in using it. If you used different strings than the one shown in your question, no need to show anything...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, , when I used your code I didnt notice that string was a bit different from original string I used in the script (I removed some part of path in https link. So when I made comment that code gives wrong result and used "path" word you pointed that there should be exact much so I re-checked whole string and found difference between part of the string in your code and original string so I just changed that and it started to work perfect. So as I said - your code works just fine and there was my bad.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the vba Replace() function, You can set multiple replaces by:

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(put here 3 replace conditions)))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function